# Java jScrollPane not displaying scollbars

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jeditorpane

I'm trying to get scrollbars working on my scroll pane. Originally my pane had been just a editor pane that loaded a webpage. However, I did research and found out you can't add scrollbars natively to that kind of jSwing element. So, I made a jScrollPane and added a jEditorPane to it. Everything works great except I can't figure out why there are no scroll bars appearing and the pane is completely unscrollable. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
public Main() {
    initComponents();
    scrollWeb.add(editorWeb);
    editorWeb.setEditable(false);
    editorWeb.setSize(scrollWeb.getWidth(), scrollWeb.getHeight());
    try {
        editorWeb.setPage("http://www.futureretrogaming.tk/news.html");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: I did not do that. I will give that a try

Comment: @Kyle, There is no need to use that method. All that method does is resevere space for the scrollbar and always paint it. It will not be functional unless the scrollpane is created properly and the preferred size of the component added to the scrollpane is greater than the size of the scrollpane.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, ya the method that worked the best is the one below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> scrollWeb.add(editorWeb);

Don't add components to the scrollpane. Intead you add components to the viewport of the scrollpane:

```
scrollWed.setViewportView( editorWeb );
```

Or, when you create the scrollpane you can use:

```
scrollWeb = new JScrollPane( editorWed );
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will scroll if you force the size of the component held by the JScrollPane's viewport to the same size as the JScrollPane:

```
editorWeb.setSize(scrollWeb.getWidth(), scrollWeb.getHeight());
```

Just simply don't do this since this constrains the size of the JEditorPane to be the JScollPane's size and no larger, so it will never expand. Instead let the editorWeb be a larger size based on its content.